# Django admin - giving users access to specific objects/fields?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-permissions

I need to make an "owners" login for the admin. Say we have this model structure:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    owner = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, through='ProductPhoto')


class Photo(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
    alt = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class ProductPhoto(models.Model):
    photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

We have a group called `Owners` that some users are part of. The `ProductPhoto` is a `TabularInline` on the `Product` admin page.

Now, owners need permission to edit

1. **(primary goal)** *only* products where `product__in=user.products` (so basically, only products owned by them).
2. **(secondary goal)** *only* the **description** and **photos** of products

How would I do this with Django's admin/permission system?

Answer (score 4):

This is row (or object) level permission. Django provides basic support for [object permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#handling-object-permissions) but it is up to you to implement the code.

Luckily, there are a few apps that provide drop-in object-level permission framework. [`django-guardian`](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) is one that I have used before. [This page](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/) on djangopackages.com provides some more that you can try out.

Comment: Actually - this is a better djangopackages page: http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/

Comment: Ah, field level is what I need also now. Is there a way to implement this on top of guardian? Or does another framework provide this?

Answer (score 0):

You may implement using get_form. For complex rule, you can add this too: https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules

```
  def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)        
    # permission check;         
    if form.base_fields and not request.user.is_superuser:
        # when creating or updating by non-reviewer (except superuser)
        # allow only reviewer to allow updating
        form.base_fields['usertype'].disabled = True
```