# DJANGO - Assign permissions from Admin Panel to an user only for some objects from Model

Tags: django

DJANGO

In ADMIN PANEL using my superuser account I want to give permissions at users to view/change/delete to **some objects** , not all of them from a Model.By default in ADMIN PANEL you can give permissions for entire Model and not for some objects from it(Model).

I will give you an example:

```
class Professor(models.Model):
user                = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
lastname            = models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True,blank=False)
firstname           = models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True,blank=False)
email               = models.EmailField(max_length=40,null=True,blank=False)


class Course(models.Model):
name            = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=False)
professor       = models.ForeignKey(Professor,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
content         = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True,help_text='')
```

For example I will create 3 courses: X,Y,Z.
The professor teaches Y and Z.
The flow is:with my superuser I will create an user for this professor from Admin Panel and I will give him STAFF STATUS and I want to give him also permissions only for 2 objects from Model Course (Y and Z) not for all.All of these I want to be changed from Admin Panel to be easier.

How can I do that?

In the final I want to be easy to give permission from ADMIN PANEL not to entire Model but to some objects from it.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053122/controlling-django-auth-user-access-to-specific-object-instances

Comment: or this https://stackoverflow.com/q/11138479/7692463

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the django admin you can use the [`has_change_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission) method of [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin):

```
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj is None:
            return True
        return request.user == obj.professor
```

Note: the first check on `None` is needed as the documentation says:

> if obj is **None**, should return **True** or **False** to indicate whether viewing of objects of this type is permitted in general.

This works, but the list view still displays all the `Course` objects. Making it hard for professors to know which ones they are allowed to edit. We can change the objects displayed in the list view using the [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method:

```
class CourseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        return queryset.filter(professor=request.user)
```

Note: you might want to edit both methods for superusers.